# DIV inside of DIV appendTo with .data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, draggable

I am trying to apply a **div with a div inside**, to a specific element on my page, with **appendTo** and then make it draggable. Applying a sole dive with **appendTo** and making it draggable works fine. What I cannot figure out is how to put a div inside of the div that I use **appendTo** on.

I will post the script that works first and then the one that does not, with the extra div inside.

**Script that works:**

```
$('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).attr('class', 'rtitle').appendTo($("#" + id).parent()).draggable({
  containment: '.site-wrapper',
  stack: '#testpile div',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
}).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

**Script that does NOT work:**

```
$('<div>' + ('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).attr('class', 'rtext text-justify') + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).attr('class', 'rtitle').appendTo($("#" + id).parent()).draggable({
  containment: '.site-wrapper',
  stack: '#testpile div',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
}).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

I am quite sure that my syntax is incorrect or that I am simply using the wrong kind of mechanic to do what I want to do.

Comment: In your second script, that + '</div>' seems really out of place, in a syntactically incorrect way. Also, I had no idea you can use $('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>') like that, TIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to combine jQuery object and HTML string and functions, which is the problem.

The first rule is to try to format the code in a way it makes sense to you. Then it will be very easy to figure out where exactly it went wrong.

Lets try to break down your code.

This part

```
$('<div>' + ('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).attr('class', 'rtext text-justify') + '</div>')
```

should be like this

```
$('<div>')
  .append(
    $('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>')
      .data('number', next[i])
      .attr('id', +next[i])
      .attr('class', 'rtext text-justify')
  )
```

Complete code

```
$('<div>')
  .append(
    $('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>')
      .data('number', next[i])
      .attr('id', +next[i])
      .attr('class', 'rtext text-justify')
  )
  .data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).attr('class', 'rtitle')
  .appendTo($("#" + id).parent())
  .draggable({
    containment: '.site-wrapper',
    stack: '#testpile div',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true
  }).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: You solved it that quickly and even informed me what I was doing wrong, thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: @user2304993 My pleasure. Happy coding.